# Difference between two string list without using SET

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have two string lists:

```
list1 = ["python", "java", "perl", "sql"]
list2 = [ "scala", "python", "perl"]
```

I need a difference list like:

```
difference = ["java", "sql", "scala"]
```

I tried:

```
def stringDifference(list1, list2):
    difference = []
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            difference.append(i)
    for i in list2:
        if i not in list1:
            difference.append(i)
    print difference
```

But I just wanted to see if there is any efficient way than this solution in Python version less than 3.

Comment: Why do you not want to use set?  sets are present in Python 2 as well as Python 3?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz, I just want the solution to be more algorithmic.

Comment: @anbu I provided a solution below, but know that using `set` intersection is far more efficient, I'm not sure what you think will be more "algorithmic" by avoiding `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can leave the lists as they are, it's likely faster to turn them both into dictionaries first which allow fast membership testing like sets do:

```
list1 = ["python", "java", "perl", "sql"]
list2 = [ "scala", "python", "perl"]

d1 = dict.fromkeys(list1)
d2 = dict.fromkeys(list2)
difference = [i for i in d1 if i not in d2] + [i for i in d2 if i not in d1]

print difference
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the result of two list comprehensions

```
>>> list1 = ["python", "java", "perl", "sql"]
>>> list2 = [ "scala", "python", "perl"]
>>> [i for i in list1 if i not in list2] + [i for i in list2 if i not in list1]
['java', 'sql', 'scala']
```

Comment: FWIW I don't think this is a particularly more _efficient_ solution (correct me if I'm wrong), but it's a lot more Pythonic and nicer to look at.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You are correct, it is less efficient than using `set`'s, this is almost a perfect use case for `set`. Also the above solution leaves duplicates in the resulting list, I don't know how the OP wanted to handle that.

Comment: Right; I concur it is far less efficient than sets. I meant to comment that yours is probably the same efficiency as OP's solution.

Answer (score 0):

using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list1 = ["python", "java", "perl", "sql"] 
>>> list2 = [ "scala", "python", "perl"]
>>> [ x for x,y in Counter(list1+list2).items() if y==1 ]
['sql', 'java', 'scala']
```

using count:

```
>>> my_list = list1+list2
>>> [ x for x in my_list if my_list.count(x)==1 ]
['java', 'sql', 'scala']
```

set is better but you asked:

```
>>> [x for x in list1 if x not in list2 ]+ [ x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
['java', 'sql', 'scala']
```